# GNU/Linux substitute for the Windows-based TreeComp tool

Tags: linux

I miss the [TreeComp](http://lploeger.home.xs4all.nl/TreeComp3.htm) tool from Windows on Linux. Does anybody know about a similar tool for Linux?

I've tried Unison & Unison-gtk (slow and cumbersome), diff (various), meld, mc, rsync (immensely configurable, my actual solution for backing up things, but not interactive), etc.

Comment: Regarding Unison: It can be slow if you are using it on a network filesystem directly, due to the consistency checks Unison makes. However, it becomes really fast if used over SSH.

Comment: As I read in the TreeComp description, it is just a GUI for the windiff program, and the source for that program is available (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinDiff). So you could take that as an example (you can't port that to UNIX) and make a neat X11, Qt or Gnome version of it.

Comment: I did not read the docs but I used the program for many years... The strong feature of TreeComp is the ability to sync entire branches just by rightclicking on the top node of the branch :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/).

Comment: very close, thank you
the only negative remark about FreeFileSync is that it shows the differences using a "spreadsheet" GUI component instead of a collapsible tree

Comment: @atrent That's no longer the case, at least in the Mac version of the app.